# SPSS equivalent to Excel IFS statement

Tags: function, spss

I am wondering how can I have it so that if the value in one column is 1, the value in this column is 5, and if the value is 0 the value in this column is 10.

With what I've seen I am only able to have it so that if the value in one column is 1 the value in this column is 5, and if the value is anything else the cell in this column is blank.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it (and yes, so much easier than `ifs` :) -

```
recode thiscolumn (1=5)(0=10) into thatcolumn.
```

Now this solves your example, but `recode` can also solve more complex scenarios. Here I combine a few examples:

```
recode thiscolumn (lo thr 0=-1)
                  (0 3=sysmis)
                  (1 2 4=1)
                  (5 thr 12=12)
                  (22 thr hi=22)
                  (miss=99)
                  (else=copy) 
        into thatcolumn.
```